Django model.objects.filter not working properly
So I am trying to use this:
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=self.kwargs['pk'])

To search my OrderItem by object and return only the ones linked to a specify order by an order_id.
However using the Django debug_toolbar I can see what the sql query is doing and it is doing the following:
SELECT "littlelemonAPI_orderitem"."id",
       "littlelemonAPI_orderitem"."order_id",
       "littlelemonAPI_orderitem"."menuitem_id",
       "littlelemonAPI_orderitem"."quantity"
  FROM "littlelemonAPI_orderitem"
 WHERE ("littlelemonAPI_orderitem"."order_id" = 2 AND "littlelemonAPI_orderitem"."id" = 2)
 LIMIT 21

In this case I passed 2 as the PK in my API endpoint but I don't understanding why it is searching by the id when I only want it to search by the order_id.
These are my database tables:


Also these are how these two models are defined:
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivery_crew = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='delivery_crew',null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=0)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True,auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADEAlso)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order','menuitem')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.order_id}"

And these are the serializers I am and will be using but I am not sure how these would cause this issue:
class OrderSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','total','status','delivery_crew','date']
    
class OrderItemHelperSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = ['title','price']
        
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menuitem = OrderItemHelperSerialzier
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['menuitem','quantity']
        depth =1 

class OrderAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        medel =Order
        fields = ['delivery_crew']

I haven't really tired anything  else because I cant seem to find anything about this issue online.

I think there is no issue with the code you provided. The SQL query you took from the toolbar is the result of the "get" method used in the "retrieve" action in your view. That is why the final query set looks like that:
OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=self.kwargs['pk']).get(pk=<lookup_value>)
